# DShow Sample Code for playing video does not play the video MSDN C++

Tags: c++, video, visual-studio-2013, directx, directshow

I was referring to the example program provided [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd389098(v=vs.85).aspx) to run a video file, *in my case mp4 format* using DShow.

Refer to the complete code:

```
#include <dshow.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "strmiids.lib")
void main(void)
{
    IGraphBuilder *pGraph = NULL;
    IMediaControl *pControl = NULL;
    IMediaEvent   *pEvent = NULL;

    // Initialize the COM library.
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("ERROR - Could not initialize COM library");
        return;
    }

    // Create the filter graph manager and query for interfaces.
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
                        IID_IGraphBuilder, (void **)&pGraph);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("ERROR - Could not create the Filter Graph Manager.");
        return;
    }

    hr = pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl, (void **)&pControl);
    hr = pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaEvent, (void **)&pEvent);

    // Build the graph. IMPORTANT: Change this string to a file on your system.
    hr = pGraph->RenderFile(L"C:\\Example.avi", NULL);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Run the graph.
        hr = pControl->Run();
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Wait for completion.
            long evCode;
            pEvent->WaitForCompletion(INFINITE, &evCode);

            // Note: Do not use INFINITE in a real application, because it
            // can block indefinitely.
        }
    }
    pControl->Release();
    pEvent->Release();
    pGraph->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
}
```

However when I build the program, the build is sucessful but when I run it, the console window pops up and disappears within a second.

I referred to the comments on the same page and many others faced the same issue. However a few were able to successfully run the program.

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Is it the type of project I am selecting? I am selecting `win32 console application`. Should I select something else? Or is there something else that I am doing wrong?

Comment: It makes a big difference whether you use MP4 or AVI. There is no stock support for MP4 in DirectShow. Start with AVIs, or install [third party MP4 demultiplexer](https://github.com/roman380/gdcl.co.uk-mpeg4) to extend support for MP4 in DirectShow.

Comment: Thanks. It worked with avi file :)

Comment: I would have to agree with `Roman R.` for when I copied this into VS2013 on a Win7 64bit machine I used an `*.avi` file that was placed in the appropriate directory and it worked as expected. When I tried this with a `*.mp4` file and changed the filename within the program it gave the same exact behavior as you were describing.

Comment: @FrancisCugler Yes precisely wat happened with me as well. It worked with all the `*.avi` files. did not work with `*.mp4`